# ValueError: {''message': 'The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available'}

Tags: python-3.x, ethereum, solidity, ganache

I found an error: 
 
ValueError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available'}

while I'm deploying a solidity smart contract in infura.io (ropsten test network). But when I tried on ganache, the contract deployed successfully on ganache testRPC. 
This is code below of my Python file.

```
from web3 import Web3
from solcx import compile_files, link_code
import json

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/<PROJECT_ID>"))



def separate_main_n_link(file_path, contracts):
    # separate out main file and link files
    # assuming first file is main file.
    main = {}
    link = {}

    all_keys = list(contracts.keys())
    for key in all_keys:
        if file_path[0] in key:
            main = contracts[key]
        else:
            link[key] = contracts[key]
    return main, link


def deploy_contract(contract_interface):
    # Instantiate and deploy contract
    contract = w3.eth.contract(
        abi=contract_interface['abi'], bytecode=contract_interface['bin'])

    acct = w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount("<PRIVATE_KEY>")

    # Get transaction hash from deployed contract
    tx_hash = contract.deploy(transaction={'from': acct.address})
    # Get tx receipt to get contract address
    tx_receipt = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
    return tx_receipt['contractAddress']


def deploy_n_transact(file_path, mappings=[]):
    # compile all files
    contracts = compile_files(file_path, import_remappings=mappings)
    link_add = {}
    contract_interface, links = separate_main_n_link(file_path, contracts)

    # print (contract_interface)

    # first deploy all link libraries
    # here link is refers to the second contarct "stringUtils.sol"
    for link in links:
        link_add[link] = deploy_contract(links[link])    

    # now link dependent library code to main contract binary 
    # https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/using-the-compiler.html?highlight=library

    if link_add:
        contract_interface['bin'] = link_code(contract_interface['bin'], link_add)    

    # return contract receipt and abi(application binary interface)
    return deploy_contract(contract_interface), contract_interface['abi']



contract_address, abi = deploy_n_transact(['./contracts/Adoption.sol'])


with open('Adoption.json', 'w') as outfile:
    data = {
        "abi": abi,
        "contract_address": contract_address
    }
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

And the solidity file is of version 0.5.0.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;


contract Adoption {
    address[16] public adopters;

    // Retrieving the adopters
    function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16] memory) {
        return adopters;
    }

        // Adopting a pet
        function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
            require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);

            adopters[petId] = msg.sender;

            return petId;
        }

}
```

But I think it doesn't effect the process of deployment of solidity smart contract on blockchain test network.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to say without viewing the content of `Adoption.sol`, but maybe this answer can help you. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48639/the-method-eth-sendtransaction-does-not-exist-is-not-available

Comment: Okay thank you for the response, I edited the question and add `Adoption.sol` .